# Create additional unique ID based on three- different columns of the same table separated by '-' in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table with having 3 attributes, as listed below, I want to create additional column names as 'Special ID' which is based on Auth_Code, price & last 4 digit of card no. (these 3 combination will be separated by '-')

```
Card_No             Auth_Code   price
---------------------------------------
4439-....-....-9878 173275  13.00
4243-....-....-7537 016365  15.00
4214-....-....-0692 037406  36.00
```

how to make that happened?

Comment: Create a view instead. Or, doesn't SQL Server have "computed columns"?

Comment: @jarlh - how to do that?

Comment: @jarlh Yes, [SQL Server has computed columns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188300.aspx), so this would be the way I'd go...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create and initialize your new column, try this:

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable ADD SpecialID varchar(200)

UPDATE yourtable 
set SpecialID = 
     auth_code + '-' + price + '-' + substring(card_no, len(card_no) - 4, len(card_no))
WHERE SpecialID is null
```

Comment: what do you mean by I must update your new column value by application, or with creation of a trigger?

Comment: After add your column and update its value, how you want manage that field? Your application will be write on that field? Or you want to use a trigger so, the update of that is managed by trigger?

Comment: here i'll do bulk insert for from a csv file then i'll execute your above query to add that field, Is it the right approach?

Comment: Ok, about your bulk insert. After that, your table can be populated by other software?

Comment: Yes, it will be populated by other software

Comment: Ok, other software must write in your new column? Or you want update that with a trigger?

Comment: the software will not write anything to that table, it will simply read the data & compare it with other table based on SpecialID & show a report

Comment: Ok, so you are only run those scripts written by me

Answer (score 0):

It's generally a bad idea to add an extra column with computed values (from other columns), because the risk of data inconsistency, and also data redundancy.

If you just add a column like that, have triggers that take care of updating it!

I have two better ideas, views (ANSI SQL), and computed columns (SQL Server):

Alternative 1, view:

```
create view viewname as
select Card_No, Auth_Code, price,
       auth_code + '-' + price + '-' + substring(card_no, len(card_no) - 4, len(card_no)) as SpecialID
from tablename
```

Alternative 2, computed column:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename
ADD SpecialID AS auth_code + '-' + price + '-' + substring(card_no, len(card_no) - 4, len(card_no))
```

(Copied some code from Joe Taras' answer, thanks!)